# Pointer-Object errors

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

I've started writing a simulating program for Tetris and in the beginning of it, I started to see this errors that I have no idea what they are.
Errors:

*expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "int"
for lines 16, 51, 62, 39.
example:

```
    void bodyMeasure()
    {
        if (PlayerChoice == "Default")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
                    body[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
```

*'void' illegal with all types
for line 46.

example:

```
        if(PlayerChoice == "Defualt")
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                cout << "\n";
                for(int j=0; j<11; j++)
                    if (body[i][j] == 0)
                    {
                        cout << '-';
                    }
            }
```

*subscript requires array or pointer type

for lines 16, 39.

example:

```
                bodyMeasure();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                {
                    body[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include"Front.h"
using namespace std;
class field: public Front
{
public:
    int row, col, body;
    void bodyMeasure()
    {
        if (PlayerChoice == "Default")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
                    body[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (PlayerChoice == "Select Difficulty")
        {
            cout << "Enter the row of the Puzzle box: ";
            cin >> row;
            if (row < 11)
            {
                cout << "Your Entry should be above 11!";
                bodyMeasure();
            }
            cout << "Enter the column of the Puzzle box: ";
            cin >> col;
            if (col < 11)
            {
                cout << "Your Entry should be above 11!";
                bodyMeasure();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                {
                    body[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void DisplayBody()
    {
        if(PlayerChoice == "Defualt")
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                cout << "\n";
                for(int j=0; j<11; j++)
                    if (body[i][j] == 0)
                    {
                        cout << '-';
                    }
            }
        if (PlayerChoice == "Select Difficulty")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                cout << "\n";
                for(int j=0; j<col; j++)
                    if (body[i][j] == 0)
                    {
                        cout << '-';
                    }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `body` is not an array.

Comment: You are using `body` as if it was a 2D array (or something equivalent) but it's just an `int`.

Comment: sometimes it helps to turn things around, instead of trying to understand the error, try to understand why the code should work. Especially, why do you think `body[i][j]` should work for `int body;` ?

Comment: btw, you wrote too much code at once. You should compile, test, debug more often. Actually you should write a single line of code and only continue to write more when you know for sure that this line is ok. If you do that you will never end up in a situation where you have 3+ times the same mistake in your code and not know why  or where. Good programmers don't write lots of code, they write less. Good programmers do not make less mistakes, they know how to deal with them

Comment: BTW all this `if(PlayerChoice == "Defualt")` stuff looks very wrong. If you have two different ways that you want to display then write two separate methods to do that. Make the choice between the two different ways to display when you call one of the display methods, not inside the single display method.